# how to get address cell

Tags: excel, vba

hi when i click on hyperlink give me the address cell that i clicked

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

        Debug.Print Target.Range.Address

    End Sub
```

If I put a hyperlink in A4 and then click the link, the output I get in the immediate window is:

```
$A$4
```

This is where the hyperlink resides.